# Swing Components in Different Classes

Tags: java, swing, constructor, components, packaging

probably a simple question here working on learning to make a GUI using swing and making mild headway but hit another speed bump.  I am trying to keep GUI components grouped in different classes to keep my classes small and allow a more flexible GUI, but I have one component built how do I call it to my main class.  Posted below is code to make the frame and the component.  I would imagine there is an issue with the way I am calling but am running out of ideas on how else to call it.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.....Wasn't very clear with the question trying to add the component to the JFrame in frmMainMenu, issue is that the component doesn't appear in the Frame when run currently

Main Class with JFrame

```
public class frmMainMenu {
    public static void main(String main[]){
        //Create Frame
        JFrame frmMainMenu = new JFrame();

        //Define Layout Manager
        GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        frmMainMenu.setLayout(gridBag);

        //Add Components

        //Create Left Container
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.ipadx = 30;

        frmMainMenu.add(new comLeftToolBar(),c);

        frmMainMenu.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        frmMainMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        //Display Frame
        frmMainMenu.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Component Code

```
public class comLeftToolBar extends JPanel{
    public comLeftToolBar() {

    JPanel comLeftContainer = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout leftGridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    comLeftContainer.setLayout(leftGridBag);
    GridBagConstraints b = new GridBagConstraints();

    JToolBar comLeftToolBar = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
    b.gridx = 0;
    b.gridy = 0;
    b.ipady = 50;

    JButton comNavButton = new JButton();
    JButton comProButton = new JButton();

    comLeftToolBar.add(comNavButton);
    comLeftToolBar.add(comProButton);

    comLeftContainer.add(comLeftToolBar,b);
    comLeftContainer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working?  I'd also take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: `how do I call it to my main class` - what do you mean? You are using `new comLeftToolBar()` which is the way to create an instance of the class. Also, class names should start with an upper case character. So it should be `ComLeftToolBar`.

Comment: 1) Don't extend a panel in this instance.  Instead create & use an instance of one.  2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Most of what I have read indicates that extending JPanel is the way to go (http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/58217-accessing-gui-components-different-class.html) and eliminating the extends parts creates errors.  However I could be doing something different without knowing it, what does creating and using an instance of mean, I create one within the Component code how should i shuffle things around to try your recommendation

Answer (score 1):

> issue is that the component doesn't appear in the Frame when run currently

Your class is a panel. But then you create another panel (comLeftContainer) and add components to this panel. But you don't add any components to the  `ComLeftToolBar` panel so it remains empty.

For a simple solution, at the bottom of your class you can use:

```
add( comLeftContainer );
```

Of course this is not the best solution. This will give you a structure of:

- JPanel

  - JPanel

    - JToolbar

      - button
      - button

There is no need to have such a complicated structure. A toolbar is a component that be added directly to the frame.

If you want to create a class that you can add to the frame then take a look at the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tool Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for a better structure.